# Sort Blog Post comments by date DJANGO

Tags: django

Hi i have a problem with comments on my Blog app in Django.
Everything is working fine except that i want to display comment sorted by date (newest on top)
o and it'll be great i'll be able to put in to the author field user that is actually loged in.. TY

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
text = models.TextField()
created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def approve(self):
    self.approved_comment = True
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model = Comment
    fields = ('author', 'text', 'created_on')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is, in your models add a meta class as follows

```
   class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
```

Comment: TY it worked i can't belive i've tried to put this ordering in to a few different places but i did't figure it out to put it into meta class ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `class Meta: ordering(-date_posted)`, `date_posted` can be changed to the variable containing the `DateTimeField()`

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
blogpost_connected = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.author) + ', ' + self.blogpost_connected.title[:40]
```